# client side password encryption in login.js using RSA in javascript and decrypt in Server side in java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, rsa, struts

I am working with struts login application
I need to encrypt password in the login.js file using RSA public key in javascript and then decrypt it using RSA private key at server side in java.

I have java code which generates the RSA public/private key in server side. And saved that keys in the server side.

When user clicks on submit button after filling username and password, i will be encrypting the password using RSA public key which was generated in the server side. Than struts action will be executing which will do authentication using LDAP at server side.

**But how can i transfer public key from server to client for encryption of password at client side when user click on the submit button.**

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Just send an ajax request to the server to get the public key? But in general why are you extra encoding the password? If you're service your site via HTTPS everything is already encrypted.

Comment: Application is on HTTPS but the password field is visible in developer options in the request body, it was not encrypted

Comment: Yes ofc, but why is this a thing? When you've access to the dev tools you're also the one who entered the password^^

Comment: Also can I send Ajax request on click of submit button before executing sturts action which is responsible for authentication ? I have not much idea about ajax/client side languages

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure about the behaviour on submit buttons and click listeners. But I doubt that encryption your password synchronous than editing the DOM (you've to put the encrypted password somewhere into the form) will not work well. Especially from interest would be if the browser then posts the content of the newly edited form or just the initial form data.

Comment: browser posting newly edited form using javascript

Comment: Yes ofc, but why is this a thing? When you've access to the dev tools you're also the one who entered the password^^

Anyone if got access to the request, than he can have acccess to credentials